# CORS issue when using Wavesurfer.js to fetch audio files from Firebase Storage in React app

Tags: reactjs, cors, firebase-storage, wavesurfer.js

I'm encountering a CORS issue when attempting to use Wavesurfer.js to fetch audio files from Firebase Storage within my React application. While simple HTML5 audio tags work without any CORS-related problems, Wavesurfer.js seems to trigger a CORS error when trying to load audio files from Firebase Storage. (When I try to load audio tracks locally it works just fine.)

The specific error message I'm seeing is:

> Access to fetch at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

To provide more context, I've set up my Firebase Storage rules to allow read access with appropriate CORS configurations, and simple audio playback using HTML5 audio tags works fine without triggering CORS issues.

Here's my simplified Firebase Storage rules configuration:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null &&
                   request.resource.size < 10 * 1024 * 1024 &&
                   request.headers.origin == 'http://localhost:3000';
    }
  }
}
```

**Question**:

1. Is there something specific in the way Wavesurfer.js fetches audio files that could lead to CORS issues even with correct Firebase Storage rules?
2. Are there additional considerations or configurations needed when using Wavesurfer.js in combination with Firebase Storage?
3. Are there any known workarounds or best practices to ensure CORS-compliant audio file loading when using Wavesurfer.js in a React app?

Any insights, workaround or suggestions on how to successfully use Wavesurfer.js to fetch audio files from Firebase Storage in my React app without encountering CORS errors would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Despite these configurations, Wavesurfer.js fetches result in CORS errors. I've even tried setting the mode: 'cors' option in my fetch request, but the problem persists.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    waveSurferRef.current = WaveSurfer.create({
      container: containerRef.current,
      waveColor: ["#eadfff", "#024bff"],
      progressColor: ["#024bff"],
      cursorColor: "#024bff",
      xhr: {
        cache: "default",
        mode: "cors",
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: [
          { key: "cache-control", value: "no-cache" },
          { key: "pragma", value: "no-cache" },
        ],
      },
      responsive: true,
      height: 50,
      normalize: true,
      barMinHeight: 100,
      // barWidth: 2,
      // barRadius: 2,
      // barGap: 2,
      partialRender: true,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this problem. I made it work, by allowing cors via cloud shell in cloud.google.com with this command:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://FIREBASE-STORAGE-BUCKET
```